# How to design for an impedance matching device for non-TEM waveguides?

Tags: rf, integrated-circuit, simulation, electromagnetism, transmission-line

Let us start from the assumption that we are working with RF waveguides which do not support TEM modes. In such scenario, there is no physical (only formal) meaning to an equivalent voltage and current wave, and therefore there exists an ambiguity on the line impedance definition. However, such systems can be quite common and devices must be designed to maximize power throughput. It if were a TEM mode the solution would be to make the device impedance matched to it's input. However, since with non-TEM fields there is no line impedance definition, how do we design an RF device to maximize the power trhoughput?

## A simple use case

An example of this a simple CPW on a dielectric. This set-up can support a mode which we can call quasi-TEM (QTEM), where the longitudinal component is indeed quite small compared to the transverse components, making it a QTEM. I am modelling this device with CST Microwave Studio and in order to match to experimental results, I needed to model the metal tracks as a 3D conductor. By doing so, the software no longer classifies the mode as a QTEM, but rather as a hybrid mode. My guess is that it no longer has any polygon which it can classify as a metal, and, therefore, the calculation of current propagating through the device can't take place and being unable to calculate the line impedance. The question now is: how would I design a CPW (**and any other non-TEM device**) for impedance matching?

Comment: from wikipedia, I learn that "Hybrid electromagnetic (HEM) modes, ... can be analysed as a linear superposition of the corresponding TE and TM modes." So maybe these separate TE/TM modes have a defined characteristic impedance and therefore an impedance matching approach can be applied?